# Conditional versions in Carrierwave

Tags: conditional-statements, rotation, carrierwave, versions

I'm working on doing a simple rotate+resize on an uploaded image but only if it is landscape format. Otherwise, I just want the image resized. I also want to do this while keeping the version name the same (not have a "medium" and a "medium_rotated") So far I have the rotate working but the problem is if I upload a non-landscape image, it doesn't work at all. It only works for landscaped images. Here's the relevant parts of my code so far. Any ideas?

-Benny

```
class FloorPlanPhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ....

  version :medium, :if => :is_landscape? do
    process :rotate_cw
  end

  version :medium do
    process :resize_and_pad => [ 260, 360, :white, 'Center']
  end

  def is_landscape? picture
    file =  (picture.is_a? CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File) ? picture.public_url : picture.file
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(file)
    image[:width] > image[:height]
  end

  def rotate_cw    
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.rotate "90>"
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  ....

end
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've defined the `:medium` version twice. It's hitting the:

```
..., :if => is_landscape?
```

portion, which for non-landscape images returns false. As a result, nothing is done. The second declaration of `version :medium` you've got there never gets run, because you can't declare two versions with identical names, so it's just completely skipped.

What you need to do is produce just one version, named `:medium`, and conditionally process the clockwise rotation. Something like:

```
class FloorPlanPhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ...

  version :medium do
    process :rotate_cw, :if => :is_landscape?
    process :resize_and_pad => [ 260, 360, :white, 'Center']
  end

  ...
end
```

You're allowed to chain multiple processing steps in a single version this way. Here [is a great tutorial](http://dmathieu.com/en/rails/create-your-own-carrierwave-processors) that goes into more depth on this topic.

Comment: I think I tried that before and it didn't work because is_landscape requires a picture to be passed in and that doesn't seem to happen when you use is_landscape as an argument to process rather than version.

Is there a way to access the image object when you pass the processor method to process?

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution:

```
version :medium do
  process :rotate_cw, if: ->( uploader, args ) { uploader.model.is_landscape? }
  process :resize_and_pad => [ 260, 360, :white, 'Center']
end
```